# PCA in R: how to determine contribution of each variable to a PC score

Tags: r, pca

I'm performing a PCA in R, like below.

```
# Load data
data(mtcars)

# Run PCA
car.pca <- prcomp(mtcars, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE)
```

I get the PC scores for each car by using `car.pca$x`. So, for example, I know that for Mazda RX4 the PC1 value is -0.6468627420. What I'd like to know is, how do I calculate the contribution of each variable to achieving this value? I know that `car.pca$rotation` will give me the variable loadings. So, I'd expect something like `mtcars[1,] * car.pca$rotation[, 1]` would work (i.e., the loadings for PC1 multiplied by the data for the Mazda RX4), however, I don't think this would account for the fact that the data were centred and scaled by the `prcomp` function. How would I do the calculation while accounting for centring and scaling?

Comment: `summary(car.pca)`?

Comment: That alone just gives me the proportion of variance, etc., explained by each PC.

Comment: @yeedle Actually, that pointed me in right direction. Thanks! Solution below...

Comment: Glad I was able to be of assistance albeit unintentionally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
car.pca$rotation[, 1] * (mtcars[1,] - summary(car.pca)$center) / summary(car.pca)$scale
```